# Evaluate formula - sheets in same workbook treated as external

Tags: java, apache-poi, external, formula

I've been given an Excel workbook, with multiple worksheets that contains various formulae that reference other worksheets, *but always in the same workbook*. E.g. `=sheetname!C$26`, so there is no indication of another workbook in the original spreadsheet.

I've tried various ways of evaluating these formulae as described in the [POI documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) but they all fail with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: not implemented yet
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getExternalSheetIndex(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:127)
```

The error message is obvious, but this method takes as arguments the sheet name and the workbook name. The sheet is in the *same workbook*.

How can I get around this?

I need to populate and evaluate these formulae programmatically a very large number of times, and I'm also open to suggestions of a better way to do it!

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you trying this with? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I'm on 3.9. I'll have a look for a newer version.

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Comment: So I've upgraded to 3.12, but it turned out there were indeed references to other worlkbooks (actually older versions of the same workbook). I have got some progress using setupReferencedWorkbooks.